# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable when reversing a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I am trying to find out if a number is a palindrome. My code is:

```
max = 10 ** n
length = 0
total = 0
for i in range (max):
    if i == i[::-1]:
        total += 1
        if len(i) == n:
            length += 1
```

The line `if i == i[::-1]:` gives the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. n is an integer.

Comment: A number cannot be a palindrome. Only a string can be. Convert your number to a string `i=str(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` is an integer, yet you try to access an element from it as if it were list, via

```
if i == i[::-1]:
```

I think in this case, you want

```
if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
```

And to also cast `i` to a string inside of `if len(str(i)) == n:`

However, it might be easier to instead do:

```
for i in map(str,range(max)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `i` to a string first before trying to reverse it as a sequence. Integers otherwise can't be used as a sequence.

```
max = 10 ** n
length = 0
total = 0
for i in range (max):
    s = str(i)
    if s == s[::-1]:
        total += 1
        if len(s) == n:
            length += 1
```